# Add FileUploadItem to Google Forms in Google Apps Script programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is there a way to add a FileUploadItem to Google Forms in Apps Script programmatically?
I cannot find a function:

```
Form.addFileUploadItem() or Item.asFileUploadItem().
```

Comment: I can't find anything about a file upload item being created through apps script or through the advanced Drive API.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this example from: https://ctrlq.org/code/19747-google-forms-upload-files  or this one http://www.googleappsscript.org/user-interface/upload-doc

```
<!-- Paste this into forms.html -->

<!-- Text input fields -->
<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
<input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email">
<!-- File upload button -->
<input id="file" type="file">
<!-- Form submit button -->
<button onclick="submit(); return false;">Submit</button>
<!-- Show Progress -->
<div id="progress"></div>
<!-- Add the jQuery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

  var file, 
      reader = new FileReader();

  // Upload the file to Google Drive
  reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(showMessage)
      .uploadFileToGoogleDrive(
         e.target.result, file.name, 
         $('input#name').val(), 
         $('input#email').val()
      );
  };

  // Read the file on form submit
  function submitForm() {
    file = $('#file')[0].files[0];
    showMessage("Uploading file..");
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  function showMessage(e) {
    $('#progress').html(e);
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try to add an UploadItem via Form.addFileUploadItem() to Google Forms. Afaik, it is not possible to use HTML in Google Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Created a feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62981173

Confirmed it appears there's no good way to work around this issue, as there's no way I can find to create a generic form response without following the Item.asTypeItem() pattern.

I have an approval workflow where I take data from a file upload field and push it to a plain text field in another form, but it's not ideal.

```
// you can access the file selected from a
// form as an array of file IDs
var fileIDArray = itemResp.getResponse()


// If you want URLs to present to a user, that's a snap too...
var urlArray =  fileIDArray.map(
        function (id) {
            return DriveApp.getFileById(id).getUrl()
        })

// But alas, there is no way to push a new response
// successfully.
```